# rewind package.json dependencies to a timestamp?

Tags: javascript, package.json

Is there a way to specify a timestamp for a package.json dependency?  I want to "rewind" a project to a certain date and get the latest packages at that date.

I am not sure how I would specify this in my dependencies.  Suggestions welcome!

Comment: use a SCM. If you use git, `git log` can help you do the time travel. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the latest version of a package for a given date, you can find the package on NPM or where the code is hosted and look for the version that most closely matches the date. For example on Github you would be looking for tags or releases; on npmjs.com you would look for a date that's in the right range. Here's an example on one of [my packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-reset). If you hover over "a year ago", "2 years ago", etc., it'll show you the actual timestamp. Then you can pin to that version. If your own project is in a repo, the easiest thing to do would be to find the date, check out a commit at that time, and work from there.